# Can't Install Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-7

I tried with both the web install platform and manually but both don't work.

I am trying to first install AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe yet it always fails with a fatal error

```
OS Version = 6.1.7601, Platform 2, Service Pack 1
OS Description = Windows 7 - x64 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 1
CommandLine = c:\temp\ext27692\setup.exe
TimeZone = Pacific Daylight Time
Initial LCID = 1033
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update
Package Version = 3.0.20406.0
User Experience Data Collection Policy: AlwaysUploaded
Number of applicable items: 5
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPages.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_AspNetWebPages.msi.txt
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_AspNetMVC3.msi.txt
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\NuGet.msi) Installation failed. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_NuGet.msi.txt
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_AspNetMVC3.msi.txt
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (c:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPages.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20120618_145125927-MSI_AspNetWebPages.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:14:10).
```

I tried to do the fix [here](http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2011/03/error-0x80070643-installing-aspnet-mvc.html) but it is not working for me.

[image: Progress of installer]

I get a bit further than what you see in the above screenshot as it seems to hit what I think is nuget and then instantly rollbacks. It happens so fast I can't get a good look.

I do have Visual Studios 2010 SP1 installed.

Comment: Have you tried installing through [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)? It will make sure you have all dependencies required.

Comment: Ya that's what I first tired. It failed. My assumption was right. Nuget for some reason caused it to fail. Once I uninstalled it finally worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may need to check several options:

1. Check the `control panel` for installed versions of MVC framework
2. Follow the uninstall in descending order like 5-4-3
3. Try the following order when having nuget errors

> - Uninstall Nuget
> - Install MVC
> - Install latest nuget

NOTE: In addition to ASP.NET MVC3, if you have latest versions of MVC (4,5,6) you should remember to uninstall them by descending order.

Comment: I have same problem and i can't find "Nuget manager" or something like that. I'm using vs2010 - win7 x64. please help me if you can. tnx

Comment: I had the same problem.  I had Microsoft Nuget for Visual Studio 2010 installed.  I (1) uninstalled it, (2) installed MVC 3, then (3) reinstalled NuGet.

Answer (score 21):

How I got mine to work:

1. Downloaded and ran the `AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe`, let it extract the files but do not accept the license terms and click install
2. This created the folder `C:\temp\ext27692` and within this folder are all the required installation files and configuration used in the installation. If you view the contents of the folder you'll notice there is a `nuget.msi` installation file. Note, VS on your computer already has the latest version so no need to install this.
3. Quickly make a copy of the folder `C:\temp\ext27692`, while execution in point 1 is still running and then click Cancel. This will rollback and delete what it created.
4. Within the copy of the `C:\temp\ext27692` you made in point 3, locate the file `parameterinfo.xml` and open it using a text editor
5. Locate the following lines within the opened `parameterinfo.xml` file and delete them

   ```
   <MSI CanonicalTargetName="NuGet"
        DownloadSize="756736"
        EstimatedInstallTime="849920"
        HashValue="74F464AC4E7220775472D5DF08CE7842958BC53FB8B569E0917CEAEEFB82209C"
        InstalledProductSize="838144"
        Name="NuGet.msi"
        ProductCode="{A5630CB0-6D3C-4C93-9A51-03BEB835A982}"
        Rollback="true"
        SystemDriveSize="100">
       <IsPresent>
           <Exists>
               <MsiProductVersion ProductCode="Self" />
           </Exists>
       </IsPresent>
       <ApplicableIf>
           <Or>
               <Or>
                   <Or>
                       <LessThanOrEqualTo LeftHandSide="30319.01" BoolWhenNonExistent="false">
                           <RegKeyValue Location="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore\Version"/>
                       </LessThanOrEqualTo>
                       <LessThanOrEqualTo LeftHandSide="30319.01" BoolWhenNonExistent="false">
                           <RegKeyValue Location="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore\Version"/>
                       </LessThanOrEqualTo>
                   </Or>
                   <LessThanOrEqualTo LeftHandSide="30319.01" BoolWhenNonExistent="false">
                       <RegKeyValue Location="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\procore\Version"/>
                   </LessThanOrEqualTo>
               </Or>
               <LessThanOrEqualTo LeftHandSide="30319.01" BoolWhenNonExistent="false">
                   <RegKeyValue Location="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor\Version"/>
               </LessThanOrEqualTo>
           </Or>
       </ApplicableIf>
       <ActionTable>
           <InstallAction IfPresent="noop" IfAbsent="install" />
           <UninstallAction IfPresent="uninstall" IfAbsent="noop" />
           <RepairAction IfPresent="repair" IfAbsent="install" />
       </ActionTable>
   </MSI>
   ```
6. Save the `parameterinfo.xml`
7. Within the copy of the `C:\temp\ext27692` you made, now locate the file `setup.exe` and execute it.

This will install MVC3 but not the old version of the NuGet.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me too. Hard to imagine what MS was thinking by hard coding a dependency on an earlier version of NuGet! Cheers

Comment: This is the correct answer, you don't need to uninstall anything and it works 100%

Comment: Best answer. Instead of steps 1-4 you can simply unzip `AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe`, I used 7-zip

Comment: Life-saver! Your fix worked, when I was about to reinstall VS 2015 because of this problem!

Answer (score 15):

1. Uninstall MVC 4 using Control Panel.
2. Install MVC 3 using stand-alone installer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491 (AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe).
3. Install MVC 4 using Web Platform Installer.

It works for me. I did not touch NuGet.

Comment: This worked great; it should be marked as the answer. In short: install MVC3 before you install MVC4 if you need them both.

Comment: Agreed, this is the right solution. I had this issue after installing VS2012 and VS2013 on top of 2010.

Answer (score 2):

IF you have also previously installed ASP.NET MVC4, I also had to **uninstall Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages** from Control Panel -> Programs.

I then installed using web platform installer, and it all worked!