# Error when installing ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i have mvc 4.0 installed ,but i need mvc 3.0 tools for development ,An error occurs when i install ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update.
Thanks in advance

```
OS Version = 6.1.7601, Platform 2, Service Pack 1
OS Description = Windows 7 - x64 Service Pack 1
CommandLine = e:\temp\ext27692\setup.exe
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update
Package Version = 3.0.20406.0
User Experience Data Collection Policy: AlwaysUploaded
Number of applicable items: 8
Exe (e:\temp\ext27692\VS10-KB2483190-x86.exe) succeeded.
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPages.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetWebPages.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPagesVWD2010Tools.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetWebPagesVWD2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetMVC3.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3VWD2010Tools.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetMVC3VWD2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\NuGet.msi) Installation failed. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_NuGet.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3VWD2010Tools.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetMVC3VWD2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetMVC3VS2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetMVC3.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetMVC3.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPagesVWD2010Tools.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetWebPagesVWD2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetWebPagesVS2010Tools.msi.txt
MSI (e:\temp\ext27692\AspNetWebPages.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update_20121121_104522969-MSI_AspNetWebPages.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:17:11).
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16409867/444244 Shows how to install only the components you need. Most likely the newer version of NuGet from ASP.NET MVC4 is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common error.

Looks like solution may be found here:

- http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2011/03/error-0x80070643-installing-aspnet-mvc.html
- http://markusgreuel.net/blog/asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update-setup-fails-with-fatal-error-0x80070643
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531566
- [Can't Install Asp.net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091919/cant-install-asp-net-mvc-3)