# Trouble fixing VS 2010 ASP.Net project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, nuget, web-platform-installer

I downloaded a demo project that required ASP MVC4, and I used the Web Platform Installer to add MVC4 to Visual Studio 2010. All seemed well.

*Then* I used Nuget to upgrade the dependencies, along the way seeing that Nuget itself had a newer version which I installed.

And now I have the sequence of problems below:

1. When loading the project, VS presents what appears to be a helpful dialog below

   [image: The Web project requires missing web components to run with Visual Studio. ASP.NET Web pages with Razor syntax]
2. The Web Platform Installer looks similarly poised to do something useful.

   [image: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for ASP.NET Web Pages]
3. Uh-oh, the install craps out saying NuGet is somehow to blame and presenting a [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=266638) that leaves me at an [ASP Home Page of sorts](http://www.asp.net/mvc) but doesn't address the problem in any obvious way.

   [image: You have a newer version of NuGet installed that's incompatible with ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update]

## The Question!

How can I get my installation cleaned up and working properly?

## SOLVED

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091919/cant-install-asp-net-mvc-3) solves the problem, although the accepted answer didn't work for me (another one did)

Comment: Did you tried to install "ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax" explicitly. You can find the link -> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15979

Comment: @SBirthare. Nice try but that file offers to either "Repair" or "Remove", so the message is misleading. I did a Repair anyway but didn't fix it. I also tried to install MVC3 Tools Update using your link but that failed and again suggested NuGet as the problkem. This is a wierd one!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16409867/712526) solved the problem for me. Is that the one you're referring to? From my experience, yes this is a duplicate; however, the way this question is worded matched my situation exactly. Please don't delete it.